# JQuery doesn't set background image to div first time

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, image, background

I'm trying to set a background image to a div with JQuery. It works if there are more than one image but it doesn't work if there is a single img.

```
for(var i = 0; i<offers.length; i++)
{
   var offer = offers[i];
   var photo = photos[i];
   $('.img-product').css("background-image", "url("+photo+")");
   $('.img-product').css("background-size", "100% 100%");
   ...
}
```

I've tried to "alert" photo's value before and after `$('.img-product').css("background-image", "url("+photo+")");` statement and it works fine.

This is the result when there are more then one offer

[image: This is the result when there are more then one offer]

This is the result when search returns a single item

[image: This is the result when search returns a single item]

Comment: Can you please verify the path of the image? since in both screenshots the same image is not shown?

Comment: Path is corrent in both cases. If I search only honor 9(item that in screenshot has img) background isn't set anyway

Comment: Are you waiting for page load to finish before your code runs?

Comment: Yes. Image loading is very fast. I'm waiting for 5 minutes and... nothing

Comment: There are no changes

Comment: Browser console and symfony console are clear

Comment: .img-product {
  float: left;
  width: 37.5227272727%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);
}

Comment: I create card object on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
          code...
          $('input#search_button').click(function (e) {
             ..code
             e.preventDefault();
             e.stopPropagation();
               $.ajax({
                 ajax call..
              success: function (data) {
                   ..code
                   for(var i = 0; i<offers.length; i++)
            {
               var offer = offers[i];
               var photo = photos[i];
               $('.img-product').css("background-image", "url("+photo+")");
               $('.img-product').css("background-size", "100% 100%");
               ...
            }
}
)};
)};
```

[When I search only one item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nbaU.png)

Comment: because php controller send to ajax double array with a json response. offer array and photo array. So I have to get them by data array.
But all client-controller works fine. I've tested it

Comment: could you explain it better? All variables are insert into arrays correcly. I've print them by php and also by js.

Comment: before-->https://...amazonaws.com/.../bcaa09bc8df92c78a70a07ae85973c87.png
search-results.js:81 
after-->https://....amazonaws.com/.../bcaa09bc8df92c78a70a07ae85973c87.png
search-results.js:79 
before-->https://....amazonaws.com/.../a3621f6036e436b9aebf486fe7e51048.jpeg
search-results.js:81 
after-->https://....amazonaws.com/.../a3621f6036e436b9aebf486fe7e51048.jpeg

Comment: That's my console when I search 2 items. Console.log message are printed before and after setting bg-img

Answer (score 0):

```
var strong = document.createElement("strong");
            var founds_nbr = document.createTextNode(offers.length);
            var founds_txt = document.createTextNode(" offerte trovate");
            strong.appendChild(founds_nbr);
            founds.appendChild(strong);
            founds.appendChild(founds_txt);
            for(var i = 0; i<offers.length; i++)
            {
                var photo = photos[i];
                var offer = offers[i];

                var a = document.createElement("a");
                var article = document.getElementById("offer");
                var img_div = document.createElement("div");
                var container = document.createElement("div");
                var name = document.createElement("h4");
                var price_div = document.createElement("div");
                var offer_price = document.createElement("h1");
                var old_price = document.createElement("span");
                var expired_time = document.createElement("span");
                var title_text_node = document.createTextNode(offer.name);
                var price_text_node = document.createTextNode(offer.price);
                var old_price_text_node = document.createTextNode("35,00");
                var deadline_text_node = document.createTextNode(offer.deadline);


                a.setAttribute("href","ProductPage/"+offer.id_offer);
                /*article.setAttribute("class", "offer clearfix");
                article.setAttribute("id", "offer");*/
                article.setAttribute("style","visibility: visible");
                img_div.setAttribute("class", "img-product");
                container.setAttribute("class", "container-right clearfix");
                name.setAttribute("class", "offer-title");
                price_div.setAttribute("class", "price clearfix");
                offer_price.setAttribute("class", "offer-price");
                old_price.setAttribute("class", "del-price");
                expired_time.setAttribute("class", "expiredtime");
                $('.img-product').css({"background-image":"url("+photo+")", "background-size":"100% 100%"});
                console.log($('.img-product'));
                name.appendChild(title_text_node);

                offer_price.appendChild(price_text_node);

                old_price.appendChild(old_price_text_node);

                expired_time.appendChild(deadline_text_node);
                price_div.appendChild(offer_price);
                price_div.appendChild(old_price);

                container.appendChild(name);
                container.appendChild(price_div);
                container.appendChild(expired_time);

                article.appendChild(img_div);
                article.appendChild(container);

                a.appendChild(article);

                var container = document.getElementById("container");
                container.appendChild(a);
            }
```

@headmax

Comment: var photos = data[1];
 var offers = data[0];